# Android recycle bitmap when going back

Tags: android, button, bitmap, imageview, recycle

My app lets u choose an image then when u click next on first activity it takes u to activity num. 2 and it shows the image u've choosen there in the imageview, and when u click back then re-click next on the first activity it takes u to activity num.2 with the image u have choosen before

How do I make the imageview gets recycled when u click the button back on the activity num. 2 so it free memory when u choose a new bitmap in the first activity so I avoid OutOfMemory problem

```
    // the back button
    Back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent back = new Intent(Second.this, StartActivity.class);
            startActivity(back);
        }
    });
```

and this is the imageview

```
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.choosen_iv);
    iv.setImageBitmap(choosenBitmap);
```

I tried choosenBitmap.recycle(); but it doesn't work, when I click next on the first activity the bitmap is still there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than starting your `StartActivity` again in the `onClick` method for your back button, just call `finish()` for the `Second` activity. That will take you back to the first activity. Then when you start the second activity again (by selecting another bitmap), it will initialize everything like it did the first time through.

Comment: // the back button
    Back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
finish();
        }
    });

Comment: @AhmedAl-ekrii - In what way did it not work? Perhaps it would help to see how you start the `Second` activity. Also, are you keeping any static variable references to bitmaps anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need a back button with an `Intent` to go back to the previous activity? The hardware back button can deal with that by itself.

You can use the `onDestroy()` activity's lifecycle method to recycle your `choosenBitmap` Bitmap type variable.